# Parse.com database logic for pointers

Tags: database, parse-platform

Just for my info because I tried to figure out last time even asked their support but unfortunately still no answer.

It's a simple problem I think but I can't wrap my head around.

Let's say I have a object A,object B, object c.

I query to object A that has a pointer to object B. I get all the data back with include key and it works nice. But object B has also a pointer to object C. That data is empty. How can I get that pointer data too in the same query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these columns:

```
ObjectA:
    pointerToB : Pointer<ObjectB>

ObjectB:
    pointerToC : Pointer<ObjectC>
```

You use dot-syntax, in JavaScript:

```
objectAQuery.include("pointerToB.pointerToC");
```

You have to use the column names, the above will cause both to be populated.

Comment: Perfect! thanks (waited a month for that!!) So just to be sure. if i had also pointer in c to D i had to include it like this pointerToB.pointerToC.pointerToD (if i want the information from D also)

Comment: @MichaelAngelo yes, I'm not aware of any limit to how deep your pointers can go, other than the usual 100 record default, 1000 record max per query.